# How to repeat an input command if input is invalid in c++

Tags: c++, loops

I have to write a program that calculates GPA with several user inputs.

I've gotten the program to correctly calculate the GPA if the inputs are correct, however, the program must also have error checking i.e. if the user inputs 5 when the inputs actually needs to be 0,1,2,3, or 4. I need to be able to tell the user that the input is invalid AND have the program go back a step and allow them to retry.

The program cannot use arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{

//Defining variables that will be used during code.
float CreditHours;
int LetterGrade;
float Total;
float TotalCredits = 0;
float TotalPoints = 0;
//Asking for input from user
cout<<"Please enter the grade for your class: 4 for A, 3 for B, 2 for C, 1 for D, 0 for F,  or  '-1' when you're done inputting grades:\n";    

cin >> LetterGrade;
// Logic to ensure valid letter grade input
if ((LetterGrade >= 4) && (LetterGrade <= 0))
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid input (0, 1, 2, 3, or 4):\n";
    cin >> LetterGrade;
}

cout << "Please enter the credit hours for the previously entered grade: \n";

cin >> CreditHours;


//initializing the loop for more grade inputs
//FIX LOOP
while (LetterGrade != -1)
{

    //Updating Totals
    Total = LetterGrade * CreditHours;
    TotalPoints = TotalPoints +  Total;
    TotalCredits = TotalCredits + CreditHours;

    cout << "Please enter the grade for your class: 4 for A, 3 for B, 2 for  C, 1 for D, 0 for F, or -1 when you're done inputting grades:\n";

    cin >> LetterGrade;

    if (LetterGrade != -1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the credit hours for the previously entered grade: \n";

        cin >> CreditHours;
    }
}//close loop
//Incomplete/Questionable

if (TotalCredits <= 0)
{
    cout << "Please be sure your Credit Hours add up to a positive, non-zero value\n";
}
else if (TotalCredits > 0)
{
    //Calculating and printing the final GPA.
    float gpa = TotalPoints / TotalCredits;

    cout << "Your GPA is:"<< gpa <<endl;
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guga00 answer seems correct. Also, note that you should change your condition to check for a valid letter. You're currently checking if *LetterGrade* is both bigger than 4 and smaller than 0, which will never be true. Try to use the following:

```
if ((LetterGrade > 4) || (LetterGrade < -1))
```

I changed the && (AND) for || (OR). That checks if *LetterGrade* is either bigger than 4 or smaller than -1. It will return *true* if the input is invalid. I've added -1 to allow you to detect the end of input.

Comment: One more follow up question: Is it necessary to have the non loop input/output code in the beginning AND the loop with the same input/output code after? Or can I just have to loop?

Comment: You can have only one loop. Also, you should initialize LetterGrade to something other than -1 (like 0) when you declare it, or else it will have a random value (trash) in the first comparison of _while(LetterGrade != -1)_

Comment: It doesn't seem to be misbehaving. At any rate, do yo mean at the very beginning? so i would have ... int LetterGrade = 0?

Comment: Yes, and it would be very unlikely for it to fail even if you don't initialize it, as it can take on a huge amount of random numbers, and only -1 will cause it to fail. Still, it's better to initialize it.

Comment: Last thing, when I first started this, I was trying to sort of go off of a lab we did recently and I started my loop with: while (LetterGrade != -1), but it made me input -1 for both LetterGrade and CreditHours before it would kill the loop. So I put in the conditional if statement before it moved on to the Credit hour input. Do I need both of these?

Comment: Yes, inside the _while (LetterGrade != -1)_, you should first read a new value of LetterGrade, and if it is valid, then you have two options: it can be -1, or a grade. Check if it is not -1 before asking for credit hours (in the code from your question, put the _if (LetterGrade != -1)_ after you confirm that the letter is valid)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your if statement to a while loop, so that the program doesn't continue until a valid number/datatype is entered. You could also use isdigit() to check if the input is a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a while condition:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{

//Defining variables that will be used during code.
float CreditHours;
int LetterGrade;
float Total;
float TotalCredits = 0;
float TotalPoints = 0;
//Asking for input from user
cout<<"Please enter the grade for your class: 4 for A, 3 for B, 2 for C, 1 for D, 0 for F,  or  '-    1'     when you're done inputting grades:\n";    

while (true)
{
    cin >> LetterGrade;
    if ((LetterGrade >= 4) && (LetterGrade <= 0))
       cout << "Please enter a valid input (0, 1, 2, 3, or 4):\n";
    else
        break;
}
cout << "Please enter the credit hours for the previously entered grade: \n";

cin >> CreditHours;
```

Comment: So, I would put that after anytime I ask for input?

Comment: Not after, you ask for the input inside the while loop

Comment: Hmm, its still not working.. The program is just skipping over that while loop when I put in like 5 for example.

Comment: memo1288 pointed out a important detail that I skipped, you have to change the operator && to || , sorry for not pointing that out